# open word document with visible=false

Tags: c#, vsto, word-2007

I see that when calling the Application.Documents.Open method in word vsto there is a reference to set if the document is visible or not. How can I, afterwards, check if the document is visible or not?

Basically i'm trying to prevent something to happen when I open certain documents by having the visibility set to false so that I can catch it with an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried yourWordDocument.ActiveWindow.Visible?